# fragment onAttach(context :Context) is not called

Tags: android, android-fragments

I saw many people use fragmentManager for activity to fragment call. So I tried that too. When I click toolbar first, I got the error like this.

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property mActivity has not been initialized
```

even though I override and initialize that method, can't see the log when starting onAttach. Why I can't initialize activity? Myfragment is DaggerFragment.

*Main button click*

```
       binding.toolbar.setOnClickListener {
            currentFramgnet = MainPictureFragment().instance
            changeFragment(this@MainActivity, binding.fragmentContainer, currentFramgnet!!)
            (currentFramgnet as MainPictureFragment).changeDataset("button OnClick")
        }
```

*Main changeFragment*

```
    fun changeFragment(activity: AppCompatActivity, view: View, fragment: Fragment) {
        val fragmentManager = activity.supportFragmentManager
        fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(view.id, fragment)
            .commit()
    }
```

*Fragment changeDataset*

```
    fun changeDataset(mes : String){
        showLog("changeDataset : "+mes)
        showToast(mActivity,"11111")
    }
```

*Fragment onAttach*

```
private lateinit var mActivity :Activity
    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        showLog("onAttach")
        if (context is Activity) mActivity = context
    }
```

updated : I logged this and found that the changeDataset is called before onAttach()

```
D/TAG: changeDataset : button OnClick
D/TAG: onAttach
```

Comment: You're most likely accessing the `mActivity` variable _before_ it is declared in the `onAttach` lifecycle hook - I suggest you should remove the `lateinit` modifier and mark it as nullable.

Comment: To add to that, you don't need to manage a private activity field yourself. Just use `requireActivity()` where necessary.

Comment: I changed like this `private var mActivity :Activity?=null`. But result is same. I got null exception. Also I changed ` showToast( requireActivity(),"11111")`, but it is same result..

Comment: Do I have to use class MainFragment(context : Context)? I just used class MainFragment()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you try to access Context before fragment transaction execute because you use `commit()`. Easy way to fix it is using `commitNow()`.

Comment: Amazing!! it's working well, I will study commit vs commitNow, Thank u!!

Comment: Actually when you call commit it schedule your transaction instead of execute immediatly.